# Mikrotik Hotspot Social Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to implement a Hotspot with Mikrotik (https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Hotspot/Walled_Garden) and the social login of facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button) as access to the network, the problem is that I must allow access to certain URLs and paths, but I do not know how the Facebook domain system works.

I pass an image with the requests made by the social login page [Facebook login button requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBLrB.png), I know that I have to allow them all but sometimes the path changes dynamically, some idea of ​​how Facebook works in this case? How does the login button work? Or simply how should Mikrotik allow social Facebook login?

Sorry for my bad english.